# Endless Repeating Error in finding Prime Number in Python

Tags: python, infinite-loop, primes

I type a Python program to find the nth prime number.

```
def prime(a, b = 2):

    def prime(a, b=2):
        def gcd(x, y):
            if (x % y == 0):
                return y
            else:
                return gcd(x, y - 1)

        if (gcd(b, b-1) > 1):
            return prime(a, b+1)
        elif (a - 1 > 0):
            return prime(a-1, b+1)
        else: return b
```

It successfully outputs the 94th prime number as prime(94) --> 491.

However, I got an endless repeating error output when I calculate the 95th prime number. Why this happen? Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

94 is the `maximum recursion depth` for python. You can increase the maximum recursion depth or you can use an iterative method rather than your current recursive one. Just to be clear, recursion is when you call a function from inside itself. To increase maximum recursion depth:

```
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(2000)
```

You should be able to come up with an iterative version yourself. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Murray! Much appreciate on your help.

Comment: No problem ;) but if you could click on the tick to the left of this answer to give me a bit more rep... :D

Comment: sure :)  just click :D